# Why is the drift of an Itō process considered to be a Riemann integral even when it's not even Riemann integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion with respect to $\mathcal F$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue integral on $[0,\infty)$

> I've read the following: Let $\sigma$ and $b$ be real-valued $\mathcal F$-progressively measurable stochastic processes on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\int_0^t\sigma_s^2+|b_s|\;{\rm d}s<\infty\tag 1\;\;\;\operatorname P\text{-almost surely}$$ for all $t\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $$X_t=\int_0^t\sigma_s\;{\rm d}B_s+\int_0^tb_s\;{\rm d}s\tag 2$$ is called **Itō process** with diffusion coefficient $\sigma$ and drift $b$.

However, some things are weird about that definition:

1. People state that $(1)$ and the second integral in $(2)$ are Riemann integrals. But unless the points of discontinuity of the paths of $b$ form a $\lambda$-null set, it is *not* Riemann integrable and hence $(1)$ is not even defined (as a Riemann integral). So, shouldn't $\int_0^t{\rm d}s$ be replaced by $\int_0^t{\rm d}\lambda(s)$? In that case $(1)$ would ensure, that almost surely the paths of $b$ are $\lambda$-integrable on $[0,t]$ for any $t\ge 0$ and thereby the second integral in $(2)$ would be almost surely well-defined (as a Lebesgue integral).
2. But we still got a problem: Since the second integral in $(2)$ is only well-defined on $\Omega\setminus N$ for some $\operatorname P$-null set $N\subseteq\Omega$, the integral and thereby $X_t$ is undefined on $N$. So, do we in fact need to replace $X_t$ on $N$ by something well-defined?

Comment: "But unless $b$ has (surely) continuous paths, it is not Riemann integrable": Why do you say that?  There are lots of functions that are [Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) which are not continuous.  For instance, [every cadlag function has at most countably many discontinuities](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502162/cardinality-of-set-of-discontinuities-of-cadlag-functions) and hence is Riemann integrable.

Comment: For your second question, sure, replace $X_t$ by $0$ on $N$, or anything else you like.  Nobody cares what happens on a null set.  All the theorems you want to prove say "a.s." everywhere anyway.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right and I've updated the question. But the point is that we still can't conclude that $t\mapsto b_t$ is Riemann integrable. So, I think we need to consider $(1)$ and the second integral in $(2)$ as a Lebesgue integral. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It should be Lebesgue integral, instead of Riemann integral. See

https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/failure-of-pathwise-integration-for-fv-processes/#more-659

Second paragraph after Lemma 1, it is specifically stated: it can be shown that if V is a continuous FV process, then a predictable process {\xi} is V-integrable if and only if it is almost-surely Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrable.

In your case, $V(t) = t$, and Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrable is now simply Lebesgue integrable.