# Why cadlag Processes have atmost countable discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Hi Guys I was trying to understand a proof on mathstack exchange by @Lord_Farin and I cannot really follow the proof. Can some body help me here?(Please see my doubts in bold)

[Cardinality of set of discontinuities of cadlag functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502162/cardinality-of-set-of-discontinuities-of-cadlag-functions)

It clearly suffices to prove that there are only countably many discontinuities on any interval $[0,n]$.

The existence of left- and right-hand limits means that for all $x$ and for all $N$, there exists an $\epsilon_{x,N}$ with:

$$\forall y,z \in B(x; \epsilon_{x,N}): (y-x)(z-x) > 0 \implies |f(x)-f(z)| <\frac1N$$

where the antecedent ensures that $y$ and $z$ are on the same side of $x$.

**Why is this last statement  even true? . It would be clear if it was continuous but the author is just using existence of left and right limits. Where do we even use the point $y$**

By compactness of $[0,n]$, finitely many of the $B(x;\epsilon_{x,N})$ cover $[0,n]$.

That is, except for finitely many points (the centers $x$ for the covering balls), we can be sure that no discontinuity of size bigger than $\frac1N$ exists in $[0,n]$.

**This last statement is not clear to me at all. I mean the existence of finitely many open balls with center $x$ tells me if I assume (which i don't really understand why) what is written above is true then at these finitely many points there are no jumps/discontinuities?**

Thus, for each $N$, the set:

$$\left\{x \in [0,n]: \left|\lim_{\xi\to x^+}f(\xi) - \lim_{\xi\to x^-}f(\xi)\right| > \frac1N\right\}$$

is finite. It follows that the set of discontinuities on $[0,n]$:

$$\left\{x \in [0,n]: \lim_{\xi\to x^+}f(\xi) \ne \lim_{\xi\to x^-}f(\xi)\right\} = \bigcup_{N \in\Bbb N}\left\{x \in [0,n]: \left|\lim_{\xi\to x^+}f(\xi) - \lim_{\xi\to x^-}f(\xi)\right| > \frac1N\right\}$$

is countable, and hence so is:

$$\left\{x \in [0,\infty): \lim_{\xi\to x^+}f(\xi) \ne \lim_{\xi\to x^-}f(\xi)\right\} = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}\left\{x \in [0,n]: \lim_{\xi\to x^+}f(\xi) \ne \lim_{\xi\to x^-}f(\xi)\right\}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first statement is false (and indeed, it is true if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x$), and is what confused you.  The correct statement is:

$$\forall y,z \in B(x; \epsilon_{x,N}): (y-x)(z-x) > 0 \implies |f(y)-f(z)| <\frac1N.$$

Here's the rest of the argument.

For each $N$, $\cup_{x} B(x;\epsilon_{x,N})$ is an open cover of $[0,n]$ and therefore there exists a finite subcover. Let $\Lambda$ denote the  set of centers of the subcovers, ranging over all $N\in {\mathbb N}$. Then $\Lambda$ is countable. Let $z  \not \in \Lambda$. We show that $f$ is continuous at $z$. For every $N\in {\mathbb N}$ there exists $x_N \in \Lambda$ such that $z \in B(x_N;\epsilon_{x_N,N})$. Let $\delta_N=\min (|x_N-z|,\epsilon_{x_N,N}-|x_N-z|)$. Then if $|y-z|<\delta_N$, it follows that   $y \in B(x_N;\epsilon_{x_N,N})$ as well as $(y-x_N)(z-x_N)>0$. As a result, $|f(y)-f(z)|<\frac{1}{N}$. Since $N$ is arbitrary, this implies that $f$ is continuous at $z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing it up. I have  another question. Why does the existence of left and right limits at x imply that $|f(x)-f(y)| < 1/N$ in that ball. I am confused since we cannot imply the nearness of the function values at $y$ and $z$ in the ball even thought $y$ and $z$ are close enough since no assumption on continuity is assumed.  Thank you in advance .

Comment: Ah sorry my bad . So left and right limit imply that since $\lim_{x_n \to x } f(x_n)=L $ implies that $|f(y)-f(z))|$ becomes arbitrarily smaller given the choice of $\epsilon_{x,N}$

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the wonderful explanation. I am grateful and very much appreciate the effort.