# For cadlag functions $x,y$, if for each $t$ $x(t)=y(t)$ or $x(t)=y(t-)$ then $x=y$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity

Let $x,y$ be cadlag functions on $[0,\infty)$. Suppose for each $t$, either $x(t)=y(t)$ or $x(t)=y(t-)$, then how does this imply that $x=y$? I am not sure how to show that for the case $x(t)=y(t-)$, we have in fact $x(t)=y(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

[Càdlàg functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) are everywhere right-continuous, and have  left limits everywhere.

Let
$$
 A = \{ t \mid \text{$y$ is continuous at $t$}\}
$$
For all $t \in A$ we have $y(t-) = y(t)$, and consequently $x(t) = y(t)$.

In [Cardinality of set of discontinuities of cadlag functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502162/cardinality-of-set-of-discontinuities-of-cadlag-functions) it is shown that càdlàg functions have at most countably many discontinuities, so that the complement of $A$ is at most countable.

Therefore, for $t_0 \notin A$ we can find a sequence $(t_n)$ in $A$ with $t_n > t_0$ and $t_n \to t_0$. Then $x(t_n) = y(t_n)$ for all $n$, and the right continuity implies that $x(t_0) = y(t_0)$.